# Prolog - Generate alternating symbols on backtrack: [a] ; [a,b]; [a,b,a]; [a,b,a,b]

Tags: list, prolog, dcg

I've wrapped my mind a lot and couldn't figure it out.
Is it possible to make a script that with backtrack generates lists in this format:

```
[a]
[a,b]
[a,b,a]
[a,b,a,b]
...
```

I've made one that generates two elements at a time but my head started to hurt trying to make one that generates "a" and the next time "b" and the next "a" and so on.

Here is the script for two elements at a time:

```
ab([a]).
ab([b,a|T]):-ab([a|T]).
ab([a,b|T]):-ab([b|T]).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When describing **lists**, always consider using **DCG notation**.

This makes it very convenient to focus an the **essence** of what you want to describe, without so many additional variables and arguments.

For example, consider:

```
abs --> [a], abs_rest.

abs_rest --> [].
abs_rest --> [b], ( [] | abs ).
```

Sample query and answer:

```
?- phrase(abs, ABs).
ABs = [a] ;
ABs = [a, b] ;
ABs = [a, b, a] ;
ABs = [a, b, a, b] ;
ABs = [a, b, a, b, a] ;
ABs = [a, b, a, b, a, b] .
```

See **[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)** for more information about this convenient formalism!

Comment: Thanks!
That is interesting, did not stumble upon it before and we certainly don't learn it in our course in my university, it's valuable information!

Anyway I am training my recursion kills and making generating scripts and I am not sure if DCGs will be accepted on my exam so I am still searching for a solution in the traditional way :)

Comment: If by "in the traditional way", you mean "in a less readable way", simply use the following query to get plain Prolog code corresponding to the DCG: `?- listing(abs//0), listing(abs_rest//0).` You can take its output, hand it to your instructor, and know that there is a better solution that you probably are not allowed to use, because why use a fitting formalism when there is a more complex way to express the same thing too?

Comment: Traditional wasn't the most suitable word to describe what I need.
I am trying to figure it out written only using Head, Tail and recursion properties of the lists. In such fashion:




ab([a]).
ab([b,a|T]):-ab([a|T]).
ab([a,b|T]):-ab([b|T]).

Comment: As I said: Load the DCG above, and then use `listing/1` to make your Prolog system output the lower-level code that you can use as well. Internally, your system compiles the DCG down to plain Prolog, and you can inspect the generated code with `listing/1` (if your system provides it).

Comment: Thanks mat! Seems I was kind of tired already yesterday and didn't catch that the first time, everything is clear now :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @mat that one should use **[dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)** when possible for these type of problems.

Here is a different set of rules.

```erlang
abs --> [a].
abs --> [a,b].
abs --> [a,b], abs.

?- phrase(abs, Ls).
Ls = [a] ;
Ls = [a, b] ;
Ls = [a, b, a] ;
Ls = [a, b, a, b] ;
Ls = [a, b, a, b, a] ;
Ls = [a, b, a, b, a, b] ;
Ls = [a, b, a, b, a, b, a] ;
Ls = [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b] ;
Ls = [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a]
```

Interestingly those rules started from this variation

```erlang
abs2 --> [].
abs2 --> [a].
abs2 --> [a,b], abs2.

?- phrase(abs2, Ls).
Ls = [] ;
Ls = [a] ;
Ls = [a, b] ;
Ls = [a, b, a] ;
Ls = [a, b, a, b] ;
Ls = [a, b, a, b, a] ;
Ls = [a, b, a, b, a, b] ;
Ls = [a, b, a, b, a, b, a] ;
Ls = [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b]
```

which is one of the exercises from [Using Definite Clause Grammars in SWI-Prolog](http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/dcg/)

If you prefer not to use DCG, then I agree with @mat and suggest that you use [`listing/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=listing/1) to see the DCG in standard Prolog syntax.

```erlang
listing(abs).

abs([a|A], A).
abs([a, b|A], A).
abs([a, b|A], B) :-
        abs(A, B).

listing(abs2).  

abs2(A, A).
abs2([a|A], A).
abs2([a, b|A], B) :-
        abs2(A, B).
```

As normal Prolog rules they can be used as such:

```erlang
abs(X,[]).
X = [a] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a] ;
X = [a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a, b, a]

abs2(X,[]).
X = [] ;
X = [a] ;
X = [a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a] ;
X = [a, b, a, b] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a] ;
X = [a, b, a, b, a, b]
```

Comment: The text you link to uses outdated terminology, please use a better maintained document.

Comment: @mat I take it you are referring to, `Using Definite Clause Grammars in SWI-Prolog`. I added the link for that to show that there are other similar problems, that's basically the reason for the link.

Comment: Thanks mate, for further explaining this, appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The predicate you wrote is too general:

```
?- ab([b,a]).
true
```

The cause is the following rule

```
ab([b,a|T]) :-
  ab([a|T]).
```

One could say that you describe an intermediate result which is no solution to your actual problem. To fix this, you could state than an `ab` sequence starts with `a` and the rest bust be a `ba` sequence, where `ba` sequences are again defined in terms of `ab` sequences:

```
ab([a]).
ab([a|Xs]) :-
    ba(Xs).

ba([b]).
ba([b|Xs]) :-
    ab(Xs).
```

Alternatively, you could think of `abs` as a state machine which
 produces `a` whenever the last element was `b` and vice versa.
 If we introduce an additional argument to trace the history, we arrive at:

```
abs(a,[a]).
abs(b,[b]).
abs(a,[a|Xs]) :-
    abs(b,Xs).
abs(b,[b|Xs]) :-
    abs(a,Xs).
```

Now we define an `ab` sequence as one which last prepended an `a`:

```
ab(Xs) :-
    abs(a,Xs).
```

Have fun :)